# Can't run Flask server

Tags: flask, cs50

Using CS50 IDE and trying to run Flask server. I keep getting "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: Look in the terminal where `flask run` is executed. There should be a traceback that will point you to the error.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Found the issue and it runs now. Having problems with getting "register" and "login" to work now after I put in a username/password. Working on that now!